# How use Paging and Sorting in Spring Data mongodb with custom filter?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

In Spring Data JPA we have Specifications and can use paging and sorting with specifications.

```
public interface JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

    T findOne(Specification<T> var1);

    List<T> findAll(Specification<T> var1);

    Page<T> findAll(Specification<T> var1, Pageable var2);

    List<T> findAll(Specification<T> var1, Sort var2);

    long count(Specification<T> var1);

}
```

But in MongoRepository where is no way use such functionality.
I tried with QueryByExampleExecutor, but it's very limited
Example I want filter data having year >5 and <20 how can do it? But Query I want generate dynamically

Comment: see https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1481

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below code :

```
@Repository
public class DataRepository {`enter code here`
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    public Page<Data> filterData(SearchDTO searchDTO){
        List<Data> list = null;
        Integer offset = Optional.ofNullable(searchDTO.getOffset()).orElse(0);
        Integer limit = Optional.ofNullable(searchDTO.getLimit()).orElse(10);
        int page = offset / limit;
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, limit);
        Query query = new Query();
        /** your filter condition */
        // if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(searchDTO.getName())) {
    //      query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").is(searchDTO.getName()));
    //   }
        query.with(pageable);
        list = mongoTemplate.find(query, Data.class);
        return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(list, pageable,
         ()-> mongoTemplate.count(query, Data.class));
      }

}
```